# SharePoint 2013 Changed subsite name now receiving 404 on all pages/parts within

Tags: 2013, error, sub-site, 404

I recently edited a subsite homepage within SharePoint and I am now unable to edit it back to it's original state. Every time I click on the subsite or anything within that subsite it timesout and redirects to a 404 error.

I attempted to go to Site Manager (/_layouts/sitemanager.aspx), right click the subsite and then Edit. This also timesout and I receive the same error 404 message.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

use SharePoint Designer and return previous version for this page.